# call shell command inside of a flash file

Tags: linux, flash, actionscript, shell, gnash

I want to create a basic GUI for a touchscreen panel running linux grml with fluxbox so I'm very restricted. The Gnash player is also available. Is there a way to call shell/bash commands inside a Flash file (swf)?

I want to create a GUI to control the mplayer and volume with the touchscreen... If it's not possible with Flash, what do you think is the easiest way?

Answer (score 1):

You *could* use Adobe AIR to wrap up your SWF file and then use the brand new NativeProcess API for interacting with any process in the system. For doing so, you must compile to a native app, and that's where I'm not sure AIR is compiling to something native on Linux (it compiles to dmg on Mac and to exe in Windows).

If AIR is not prepared for that yet, give a go to [Haxe](http://haxe.org) + [ScreenweaverHX](http://haxe.org/com/libs/swhx). Those are open source wrappers around the FlashPlayer.

Ping me back if you need some more help.